# Kits Error , Desktop_Qt_6_2_1_MSVC2019_64bit , How i can to use the visual studio compiler on Qt creator?

Tags: c++, mysql, visual-studio, qt

After spend a lot of time to understand how i connect to the MySQL DATABASE , i found that i should to install the visual studio in my Desktop.
now i installed the visual studio and i still found another problem with msvc Kits:

" attached the error caption"[Error Kits MSVC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2jSH2.png)

1- with "Desktop_Qt_6_2_1_MSVC2019_64bit" Kits , i have this error:
error: Project ERROR: msvc-version.conf loaded but QMAKE_MSC_VER isn't set

2- with "Desktop_Qt_6_2_1_MinGW_64_bit-Debug" Kits i have this error
(QSqlDatabase: QMYSQL driver not loaded
QSqlDatabase: available drivers: QSQLITE QODBC QPSQL
data base opened is filed )

Maybe someone can Helpe me ,
thank you in advance

Comment: You have to build the MySQL driver separately or download a binary package. Related: [https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt6-dev/sql-driver.html](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt6-dev/sql-driver.html) more info here: [https://forum.qt.io/topic/122077/build-and-link-mysql-plugin-qt6-qt-6-0-0-5-15-2-mysql-8-0-22-visual-studio-2019-with-qt-visual-studio-tools-2-6-0-7-step-by-step-64bit](https://forum.qt.io/topic/122077/build-and-link-mysql-plugin-qt6-qt-6-0-0-5-15-2-mysql-8-0-22-visual-studio-2019-with-qt-visual-studio-tools-2-6-0-7-step-by-step-64bit)

Comment: @drescherjm , thank you for your response , unfortunately ,
I tried all the tracks but  without success.

Comment: For any chance of help you would have to show your steps and what failed for you.

Comment: good news , i succeeded to connect to The MYSQL database with MinGW Kits,

Comment: now i want to connecte with MSVC2019 Kits , but without success , i did not understand this error message,

Comment: :-1: error: Project ERROR: Cannot run compiler 'cl'. Output:
===================
===================
Maybe you forgot to setup the environment?

Comment: You need to run that in a Visual Studio 2019 command prompt so it has the environment setup for your compiler. On the start menu inside of the Visual Studio 2019 folder there is "x64 Native Tools Command Prompt" and "x86 Native Tools Command Prompt" use the first one for 64 bit.

Comment: this error it's the title of my topic "Kits Error , Desktop_Qt_6_2_1_MSVC2019_64bit , How i can to use the visual studio compiler on Qt creator?" thank you for your help

Comment: @drescherjm, i did what you are saying for me but , i still have the same problem,  ( error warning in the kits  MSVC 2019)

Comment: I think the warning in the kits is independent of the MYSQL problem.

Comment: exactly , the warning in the kits depend of the Visual studio 2019